# Excel RibbonBar is not showing when Excel file is opened directly

Tags: excel, vsto

I have developed a custom Excel 2010 Add-in and custom RibbonBar using VS 2010. When I install the custom Add-in for Excel, the RibbonBar is displayed or shown properly when Excel is opened. BUT, when I double-click the Excel file (.xlsx), the ribbon bar does not show on the Menu.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Few checks that may help

1. Disable all addins installed and then open a xlsx file by
   enabling one addin in turn.
2. Start excel, create a new excel file
   save, close and open it again to check if ribbon appears. If it work
   fine for this, there could be some problem in file format or macro
   attached with the file